# SOQL to get list of Holidays associated with the business hours

Tags: salesforce, apex, business-objects

I am looking to get the **list of Holidays associated with the business hours** in salesforce. But I dont see a way to get association between these two.

Even if I query on both the object, I dont see any relationship, please guide.

```
SELECT 
ActivityDate,Description,EndTimeInMinutes,Id,IsAllDay,IsRecurrence,Name,Recurrence
Type,StartTimeInMinutes,SystemModstamp FROM Holiday
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below docs:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_businesshourssettings.htm

*BusinessHoursSettings*:

> Represents the metadata used to manage settings for business hours and holidays in entitlements, entitlement templates, campaigns, and cases. This type extends the Metadata metadata type and inherits its fullName field.
>   In the package manifest, all organization settings metadata types are accessed using the “Settings” name. See Settings for more details.

*BusinessHoursEntry*:

> Represents the application of business hours to entitlements, entitlement templates, campaigns, and cases.

*Holidays*:

> Represents a holiday and its usage in businessHours.

**Take special notice of the below:**

> `businessHours` `string` - The name of the business hours setting that applies to this holiday.